# Не включается адаптация сайта до 500px при выборе режима desktop

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Делал адаптацию для сайта. Все шло гладко, но я дошел до размера 480px в ширину. Я понял что это уже мобильный телефон, а не планшет и в хроме в режиме адаптации вместо desktop поставил mobile. И сайт резко переклинило и он перестал показывать адаптацию. Вместо этого начал показывать пк версию сайта на телефоне. Я решил что это проблема хрома, и просто вернул настройку desktop и начал дальше адаптировать. Все дошло до того как я залил сайт на хост. Открываю я значит его на телефоне. И вижу что оно отображается как версия для пк. И вот что делать не знаю:(

https://websitetestingfreelance.000webhostapp.com

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: viewport  же есть в  head ?

Comment: посмотрел с планшета ...отстойно смотрится

Comment: Viewport нету. Насчёт того что с планшета говно, то спасибо за инфу, видать де то пропустил какую то область

Comment: Добавьте viewport в head и все проблемы решаться

Comment: Говняно смотрится из-за этой проблемы, на мобайле сайт поменян кардинально. И можете полный пример кода viewport кинуть?

Comment: Откройте so в инспекторе, и с head скопируйте себе viewport либо в sublime text напишите meta:vp+tab

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Работает! Спасибо огромное!